# fetch data after user logged in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want to display data of user logged. Please tell me how can i make dynamic query. here is my code:

**CONTROLLER:**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Customers extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
        $this->load->model('customers_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['customers_data'] = $this->customers_model->getCustomers();
        $this->load->view('Admin/header');
        $this->load->view('Admin/navbar');
        $this->load->view('Admin/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('Admin/customers', $data);
        $this->load->view('Admin/footer');      
    }
}
```

**MODEL:**

```
<?php  
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Customers_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getCustomers()
    {
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('customers');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
     }
}
```

**by clicking on this link**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>customers"> <i class="la la-users"></i><span>All Customers</span></a>
```

After logged in, user will see this link, when he click on this link then fetch all data which inserted by this logged in user. currently showing all data.

Comment: Do you want to fetch all customers or logged in user? Your code is trying to get all the customers from the database. For logged in user, you need to maintain a session and then store user id in a session variable after authentication user login. Have you already done that?

Comment: We also have no idea what your database looks like so it's pretty hard for us to be able to give you a proper example. However, you should look into using [->where()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Comment: Currently fetching all data, but i want to fetch only logged in user data. yes i already store id in session after authentication. satish saini

Comment: please show where you are storing user's session info

Comment: you want to do it via Ajax (maybe) ?

Comment: Thanks guys, i solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to store logged data in session and cookies. After visiting on this page you have to check session or cookies data is set or not. If session or cookies data was set then ask for customer id from this and pass in your query as `$this->db->where(array('customer_id' => '1'))`.

Your code become.

**Controller :**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Customers extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
        $this->load->model('customers_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $customer_id = $this->session->customer;
        $data['customers_data'] = $this->customers_model->getCustomers($customer_id);
        $this->load->view('Admin/header');
        $this->load->view('Admin/navbar');
        $this->load->view('Admin/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('Admin/customers', $data);
        $this->load->view('Admin/footer');      
    }
}
```

**Model :**

```
 <?php  
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Customers_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getCustomers($customer_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('customers');
        $this->db->where(array('customer_id' => '1'))
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Customers extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            // Your own constructor code
            $this->load->model('customers_model');
        }

        public function index()
        {
    $customer_id = $this->session->customer;
            $data['customers_data'] = $this->customers_model->getCustomers($customer_id);
            $this->load->view('Admin/header');
            $this->load->view('Admin/navbar');
            $this->load->view('Admin/sidebar');
            $this->load->view('Admin/customers', $data);
            $this->load->view('Admin/footer');      
        }
    }
    ?>



     <?php  
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Customers_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getCustomers($customer_id)
    {


        $this->db->where('customer_id',$customer_id)
        $query =$this->db->get('customers');
if($query->num_rows()>0)
{

        return $query->result_array();
}
return[];
     }
}
```